# JqGrid - custom theme for modal window

Tags: jqgrid

I have two types of columns in my jqgrid table. Each type has own prefix in the column name. How to group column fields on edit form? Which function should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use `rowpos` and `colpos` property of the [formoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#formoptions) to specify the position of fields in the editing form. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/MulticolumnEdit.htm) from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10852741/315935) for more details. In [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10008082/315935) and in [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomFormEdit1.htm) (see Add form) of [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5745168/315935) you will find some examples more advanced techniques of customization of the form editing.