# jqGrid - formoptions rowpos and colpos is being used to create 3 column View form. How can you make 1 row's data field colspan the full width/

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

If I have configured the formoptions to create a form with 6 columns (3 for labels and 3 for data) and I want 1 row in the form to have 2 columns (1 for label and 1 for data that is the full width of the form), how can I do this?

I've tried using colSpan and looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006976/jqgrid-modal-colspan) example but could not get it to work.

Here's the structure of my jqGrid:

```
colModel :[ {
      label: 'Row 1 Column 1',
      name: 'a',
      formoptions: {
        colpos: 1, // the position of the column
        rowpos: 1, // the position of the row
        }
    }, {
      label: 'Row 1 Column 2',
      name: 'b',
      formoptions: {
        colpos: 2, // the position of the column
        rowpos: 1, // the position of the row
        }
    }, {
      label: 'Row 1 Column 3',
      name: 'c',
      formoptions: {
        colpos: 3, // the position of the column
        rowpos: 1, // the position of the row
        }
    }, {
      label: 'Row 2 Full Width',
      name: 'd',
      formoptions: {
        colpos: 1, // the position of the column
        rowpos: 2, // the position of the row
        }],
```

and the configuration of the view form options

```
        {
            //edit options
        },
        {
            //add options   
        },
        {
            //del options   
        },
        {
            //search options
        },
        { 
            //view options
            width : 1000,
            labelswidth :50,
            viewPagerButtons : false,
            closeOnEscape : true,
            beforeShowForm: function(form) {
                var dlgDiv = $("#viewmod" + mygrid[0].id);
                var parentDiv = dlgDiv.parent();
                var dlgWidth = dlgDiv.width();
                var parentWidth = parentDiv.width();
                var dlgHeight = dlgDiv.height();
                var parentHeight = parentDiv.height();
                dlgDiv[0].style.top = Math.round((parentHeight-dlgHeight)/2) + "px";
                dlgDiv[0].style.left = Math.round((parentWidth-dlgWidth)/2) + "px";
                var $tr = $("#trd_d"), // 'name' is the column name
                $label = $tr.children("td.CaptionTD"),
                $data = $tr.children("td.DataTD");
                $data.attr("colspan", "5");                             
                $data.children("input").css("width", "95%");
                $label.hide();                                      
         }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hide some unneeded columns in the second row of the View. The code of `beforeShowForm` could be like below

```js
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var $captionTds = $("#trv_d>td.CaptionTD"),
        $dataTds = $("#trv_d>td.DataTD");

    $captionTds.filter(":gt(0)").hide();
    $dataTds.filter(":gt(0)").hide();
    $dataTds.first().attr("colspan", 5);
}
```

I'd recommend you additionally to use `formViewing` option to specify View options. It makes the code more readable. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/4xyf0adw/

Comment: BTW - I also had to override the bootstrap CSS that I was using as it had `.form-control{display:block}` which was preventing the colspan from working. I overrode this to `.form-control{display: table-cell}` in order to fix this problem completely.

Comment: @You are welcome! Thanks for the comment about `.form-control` in Bootstrap - the information could be helpful for other developers.

Comment: @MarkT: I fixed `.filter(":gt(1)")` to `.filter(":gt(0)")` in my answer. Moreover I posted [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/062c34f58256f5fad01893352aca0c22c885a827) to GitHub, which should improve the look of View form for both Bootstrap and jQuery UI and make the forms looks closer. Please test the changes and inform me if you find any problems in the latest code of free jqGrid. See https://jsfiddle.net/ygm9kwqa/1/ and https://jsfiddle.net/3vreLt7r/. One can add `.ui-jqdialog-content .form-view-data { white-space: pre; }` to prevent wrapping of the data in View form

Comment: @MarkT: https://jsfiddle.net/3vreLt7r/1/ is the demo with both Edit and View forms

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be working well. I have not seen any issues so far but will let you know if I do.

Comment: @MarkT: Thank you for the feedback. I plan to publish the version the current GitHub sources as 4.13.6 next days. I want just make some tests before. Thus it would be good if you inform me about all bugs in the current code, if you'll fine someone.